# How to pause Flutter running in the background when iOS part uses bluetooth-central Background Execution Mode

Tags: ios, flutter, core-bluetooth, flutter-engine

My app is connected to BLE accessory using [CoreBluetooth state restoration and preservation (SRP)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW10) and is using `bluetooth-central` Background Execution Mode. This means that the native part of the app written in Swift can receive HR samples continuously even when the app is in the background. However, what I can also see is that the Flutter part of the app keeps running despite app being in `paused` lifecycle state.

I did a simple experiment and started timer in Flutter when **using** and **not using** Core Bluetooth SRP.

- when not using the SRP the Timer stopped printing into log after 20 seconds
- when using SRP the Timer kept running indefinitely as long as the BLE accessory was sending HR samples

What I'm looking for is to maintain the *typical* Flutter behavior but keep using SRP on the native side.

1. Which part of the Flutter is responsible for stopping the "execution" when app goes to paused state?
2. Can Flutter be paused despite SRP keeping the app awake (due to using `bluetooth-central` mode and receiving continuous HR updates)?
3. Is there a way to put Flutter engine to `paused` state programmatically?
4. If not, do you see any other ways to keep the *typical* Flutter engine/ViewController behavior?

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding, this feature gives you two things: the first is that if the app is suspended (process still alive but frozen), the app will be unfrozen when a BLE notification is received and continue being unfrozen for some seconds and then be put to suspended again. The second feature is that the app process can be killed completely (and all RAM erased), but the system will restart the process as soon as a BLE connection is established or a notification is received. In this case, you must have code that handles "restoration" now when the process starts again.

Comment: You are correct. In case of real time Heart Rate BLE notifications, the app almost never gets frozen, it's always in active state as the samples arrive almost every second. I'd like to mimic the exact same behavior as Flutter is doing when it's detecting that it's view controller is getting suspended and then manually start it again when view reappears.

Comment: Okay we had the similar problems while fetching the location in background, i don't know if it's applicable to you but here's how we solved it. we were using https://pub.dev/packages/background_geolocation_firebase it provides a bool which knows if flutter app is started in background after killed, i mean app is terminated but when opened by the location fetch notification. so we stored that bool in localstorage and then when app state changed based on that bool we can restart the app. so you can look into flutter_background_geolocation you should definitely find something.

Comment: if i am not wrong it's like when app started in background and when user open the app it's kind of open already so you want to manage that.

Comment: Okay had the similar problems while fetching the location in background, i don't know if it's applicable to you but here's how we did it. we were using flutter_background_geolocation to fetch location. it will open the app in background on geofence break. app is not visible but flutter engine is running. this package provides a bool which knows if flutter engine is started in background/terminated state, so we saved that bool in storage and when app state changed based on that bool we can restart the app. so you can look into flutter_background_geolocation you should definitely find something.

Comment: Not shure about what you exactly want to achieve, but do you have take a look to isolates ?
You can easily have a background isolate that is independant from the app. App can be paused or closed, but the background isolate continue to run.

Comment: @Alaindeseine that's not this type of issue unfortunately. I _don't want_ the Flutter app to run in the background, but because iOS keeps entire application live in the background when utilizing state restoration and preservation, then Flutter apps keeps running anyway as if it were in the foreground.

Comment: Please, add the sourcecode of what you have tried. This help in comprehension of your issue.

Comment: While it doesn't particularly change your question, note that SRP is not what is keeping your app running. It's the active device connection itself. SRP allows your app to be **re-launched** when data or a device becomes available after your app is terminated. The feature you're dealing with is "bluetooth-central Background Execution Mode." Again, this doesn't deeply change your question; it will just drive you to a different part of the docs in understanding what's happening. SRP by itself should not keep your app active in the absence of the device communicating.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier for clarifying the reason for keeping the app awake. I was confusing these two for a while (Bluetooth-Central Execution Mode and SRP)

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is in some sort of misunderstanding. When the flutter part is `paused,` it doesn't mean it pauses its execution by default. You have to manually pause all the needed stuff when you go to this state.

For the most "functional(non ui)" cases, those states [`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) catches are mere 'indications' rather than 'actions'... This is especially applicable when you listen to something native part emitting in the background.

Here is some explanation from the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState.html):

> **paused → const AppLifecycleState**
>
> The application is not currently visible to the user and is not responding to user input.
>
> When the application is in this state, the engine will not call the PlatformDispatcher.onBeginFrame and PlatformDispatcher.onDrawFrame callbacks.
>
> This state is only entered on iOS and Android.>

It means that the Flutter engine only skips drawing stuff on screen - all the other operations are active and will be active till the app's death. In the case of iOS, it may never happen till the explicit kill of the app. In Android, the OS can kill it in arbitrary time or not kill it - depending on the load of the OS itself.

To ignore any activity during the `paused` state, you have to explicitly and manually unsubscribe any listeners in the `paused` state and subscribe them once more in the `resumed` state. I am saying words like 'subscribe' and 'unsubscribe' because I don't know the specifics of your code - you may easily just ignore all the events or something...

If you want the flutter part not to function at all when the app is in the background, you have to kill the flutter part manually - you can do it if you established your flutter engine connection manually, not relying on `FluttFlutterViewController`, `FlutterFragment` etc. You have to have control over the code in order to do that. Afterward, when your app is in the foreground once more(to know that you would have to rely on native callbacks since when the flutter engine is dead, there is no callback in dart code), you will be able to reestablish flutter infrastructure and run it once more.

I don't recommend the latter approach since it is sooo redundant - ignoring events and/or subscribing/unsubscribing is sufficient in most cases. I think even including yours.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was considering "unsubscribing"/stopping all the Dart processes when going to the background (e.g. stopping websocket connections, cancelling SQLite database queries subscriptions, file watchers etc.), but I was really hoping to get just the vanilla Flutter experience without the need for that. I was looking into tweaking the AppDelegate and using custom ViewController so that it would hide and show FlutterViewController on lifecycle events, but it doesn't stop the engine from running (unless it's killed which in turns means app need to go through splash on resume).

Comment: Do you think that standalone Flutter overhead is small enough that cancelling database subscriptions and websockets should be enough to bring it back to "normal" battery usage? A vanilla SwiftUI app with SRP enabled and listening to HR stream same as my Flutter app uses less than 1% of battery per hour, whereas current Flutter app uses 6-7% per hour.

Comment: Well, yeah - flutter is known for such an overhead. If it is crucial for you - kill the engine and recreate it once it is needed - I was doing it - it is not that hard to do, actually. However, state preserving is not trivial.

Comment: Do you mind sharing how were you able to kill and rerun the engine? Even in pseudo-code?

Comment: Only in the custom controller - look how the usual FlutterFragment or FlutterViewController is implemented and basically do the same but detach it from UI and call FlutterEngine.destroy on pause and recreate it and attach to ui on resume.

Comment: Ok, is [this](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/bdfa8aa8f81f27a1ef89b4c118f7df3f7bc8a028/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Source/FlutterViewController.mm#L1050-L1053) what you mean by "FlutterEngine.destroy"?

Comment: may be - I am not very proficient in iOs especially on ObjectiveC

Answer (score -1):

Flutter's behavior in the background, especially when integrated with native modules, can sometimes lead to non-standard behaviors. Here are answers to your specific questions and suggestions to help you:

**1.Which part of Flutter is responsible for stopping the "execution" when the app goes to the paused state?**

Flutter's AppLifecycleState manages the different lifecycle states of a Flutter app. Normally, when an app goes to the background, it goes into the paused state, which should halt most of Flutter's activities. This is managed at the engine level.

**2.Can Flutter be paused despite SRP being on?**

When using state restoration and preservation with CoreBluetooth, the native part of your app will remain active even in the background. However, Flutter should be unaware of this background activity unless explicitly communicated via platform channels. Flutter's engine should still pause as usual unless something in your integration is causing it to remain active.

**3.Is there a way to put the Flutter engine to a paused state programmatically?**

Not directly from the Dart side. The Flutter engine will respond to iOS lifecycle events (like `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`), but you can't force the Flutter engine into a paused state from Dart.

**4.If not, do you see any other ways to keep the typical Flutter engine/ViewController behavior?**

Here are some suggestions:

**Explicitly Pause Activities:** Before your app goes into the background, you can use Flutter's `WidgetsBindingObserver` to listen for lifecycle events and pause any timers or activities you've started in Flutter.

```
  class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // Pause your timers or other activities here
    }
  }
}
```

**Platform Channels:** Use platform channels to communicate between the native and Flutter sides of your app. If the native side is aware that it's going into a background mode where Flutter should not be active, send a message to the Dart side to pause any activities.

**Check Integrations:** Ensure that your integration of CoreBluetooth or any other native modules isn't unintentionally keeping the Flutter engine awake. For instance, if you're continuously sending data from the native side to Flutter via platform channels, it could keep the Flutter engine active.

**Reconsider Architecture:** If possible, consider restructuring such that Flutter doesn't need to be aware of the background BLE activities. Collect the data on the native side and sync it with Flutter when the app comes to the foreground.

While you can't directly force the Flutter engine into a paused state, you can manage your app's activities based on lifecycle states and ensure that background activities don't unintentionally keep Flutter awake.

Answer (score -1):

## Try widgets if possible

im not sure of the exact environment of yours, but widgets can react to app state.

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class MyAppLifecycleObserver extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // Perform necessary operations or stop/pause execution.
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // Resume execution or resume any paused operations.
    }
  }
}
```